What should our custom "Off Topic" close reasons be?
Stack Exchange has recently changed how questions get closed. Part of this change includes defining three custom messages to be used as additional information when closing as "Off Topic". 

“Off-Topic” now includes site-specific close reasons
Many communities
  have decided that some questions that sound like they fall under the
  topic “headline” (“cooking”,  ”photography”, etc.) should be
  explicitly disallowed:

On our cooking site, recipe requests are
  off-topic, (but recipe replacements questions are allowed).
On
  photography – “fix my picture” questions are off topic, (but specific
  technique requests are allowed).
Stack Overflow is about programming,
  but programming questions you’d solve on a whiteboard or that ask
  what’s wrong with a large block of code are no good. 

And, as of today, they are also available to “off-topic”  close-voters
  right in the close dialogue. Users can pick one from the site’s list,
  or if none apply, they can enter a free-form one which will appear as
  a comment and as a choice for others voting to close the same
  question:

“Your question appears to be about ferret grooming, which is off-topic
  for Stack Overflow”.


As a community we should decide what three custom "Off Topic" messages will be displayed by default in the close dialogue. Please post one suggestion per answer; the three highest voted answers will be used.

Maybe a "no research effort" close reason?can't think of how I'd word it at the moment though

This search on existing closed questions might provide inspiration.

"Self-help" questions are off-topic because you should probably see a medical professional instead of trying to self-diagnose / self-treat. See: Why was my self-help question closed as off-topic?

This one was already set up when I went to check out the new feature; did Jeromy or Steven add this one? :-)

The SE team added at least one custom reason to each site I think, at UX we had 3 before we even added any

Nice! They chose the right one if you ask me!

The other big issue I have with self-help questions is that they are too localised. I.e., they don't ask a general question that will be relevant as a future artefact for the internet. Instead they focus on someone's specific set of circumstances.

Excellent point @JeromyAnglim
